# MySQL-Count consective number

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SQL query to find number position as well number and consective number count

```
CREATE TABLE Logs (
  `Id` INTEGER,
  `Num` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Logs
  (`Id`, `Num`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('4', '2'),
  ('5', '1'),
  ('6', '2'),
  ('7', '2');
```

Prefere Return

```
StartId Num Count
1       1   3
4       2   1
5       1   1
6       2   2
```

and also can i get any suggestion which function can be use with case function in MySQL Function

Comment: I don't see how you get to your output from your input, Are you showing min id for a num? how did you get 5,1,2 when input has only 5,1 then moves to 6,2, why isn't the last row 6,2,2 ie min id for num 2 with 2 occurances.

Comment: sorry about confuse, wrong count on my side, my bad. I revise the question already

Comment: i already set up template test platform, you can take a look at [SQL Database Test Platform](http://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qCNLHw5JKuqU95CBAaX8PW/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your data and expected results, I believe your expectations are inconsistent, eg you can either have 1 and 6 *or* 3 and 7.

What you need to do is group the data by successive `num` values and aggregate the results.

```
with gp as (
    select *, 
        Row_Number() over(order by id)
        - Row_Number() over(partition by num order by id) g
    from logs
)
select Min(id) Id,
    num, Count(*) Count
from gp
group by g, num
order by id
```

Comment: ya ,sorry , it should be 6